# How the value of the function ((n/m) + m-1) will be minimum when m = √n

Tags: algorithms

I'm analyzing an algorithm, the time complexity equation of this algorithm is $$\left(\left(\frac{n}{m}\right) + m-1\right)$$

Now I need to find out the value of $m$ to get the minimum value of this function.

There is mentioned that $m$ should be $\sqrt n$ to get the minimum value of the function. I want to know how do I calculate this?

$n$ is the number of inputs in the algorithm.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We first need to find the derivative of the equation, with respect to $m$:

\begin{align}\frac{\partial}{\partial m}\left(\frac nm+m-1\right)&=\frac{\partial}{\partial m}\left(nm^{-1}+m-1\right)\\
&=-1nm^{-2}+1+0\\
&=-\frac{n}{m^2}+1\end{align}

Here we note that $\frac 1m$ can be written as $m^{-1}$ and then we remember that to differentiate, we take the power down to the front, and then reduce the power by one. In this case we reduce $-1$ by $1$ to get $-2$, which we can then write as $$m^{-2}=\frac1{m^2}$$

Now we need to know when this equation is zero to find the turning points of the equation:

\begin{align}-\frac{n}{m^2}+1&=0\\
\frac{n}{m^2}&=1\\
m^2&=n\\
m&=\pm\sqrt n\end{align}

Now we need to find the second derivative to know which of these points is the minimum:

\begin{align}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial m^2}\left(\frac nm+m-1\right)&=\frac{\partial}{\partial m}\left(-\frac{n}{m^2}+1\right)\\
&=2nm^{-3}\\
&=\frac{2n}{m^3}\end{align}

At the point $m=\sqrt n$, we have \begin{align}\frac{2n}{m^3}&=\frac{2n}{\sqrt n^3}\\
&=\frac{2n}{n\sqrt n}\\
&=\frac2{\sqrt n}\end{align} which is positive so the point at $m=\sqrt n$ is a minimum. We can see that at the point $m=-\sqrt n$ the second derivative is negative so this point is a maximum

Answer (score 2):

The derivative w.r.t $m$ is $-\frac n {m^{2}}+1$ which is $0$ when $m =\pm \sqrt n$. The second derivative at $m=\sqrt n$ is positive so this value of $m$ gives the minimum.

Comment: I've formatted the equation, can you recheck, please. I'm still confused about how the derivative w.r.t m will be −(n/m2)+1